# After removing border, text not in center anymore

Tags: html, css

```css
.home {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 0px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: url(../img/b.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.home-content {
  height: 80vh;
  /* border: 4px solid red; */
}

.heading {
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div class="home-content">
    <div class="heading">
      <div>Shubham karwal</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

After removing border from .home the text Shubham karwal which was previously centered shifted towards left a bit.
What to do?
Please do help

Comment: What do you mean by "after removing border" from .home? I wrote `border: 4px solid red;` in `home` class and the text remains centered

Comment: When the border was there the text remains in center but once the border are removed text move to the left

Comment: You have 1 extra closing `</div>`.

Comment: Removing the extra div didn't helped

Comment: If its very little shift than may be its due removing border which was taking 4px space.

Comment: You don't have a border in `.home`, it's 0px wide, which means it's doesn't exist...

Comment: That's what i am trying to say that when border is applied the text is not in center when border is not applied text is not in center

Comment: can anyone tell the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add four lines to your css file:

```css
.heading div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the example with the css added:

```css
.home {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 0px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: url(../img/b.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.home-content {
  height: 80vh;
  /* border: 4px solid red; */
}

.heading {
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.heading div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div class="home-content">
    <div class="heading">
      <div>Shubham karwal</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the border is being added/removed. And also whether any other CSS settings are keeping the standard padding/margins that a browser might add to some elements or not.

The height is set at 100vh. If the box-sizing has not been altered it will default to value content, which means any padding and any borders are not included in the browser's calculation of the size of an element.

In the snippet given in the question neither the default padding/margins nor the default setting of box-zising are altered. Hence the height overall is greater than 100vh (what with the default top padding and the addition of a border) so space for a scroll bar is created on the right hand side and the text (well, the elements it is in) all shift a bit to the left.

Quite often you'll see these settings at the top of a style sheet:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

which means all three of those settings are set as given for all relevant elements unless subsequently set.

Try this in your 'real' situation to see if it cures the problem.